# How can I convert special chars into html entities

Tags: matrix, text-formatting, html-entities

One of my matrix cells for the caption/description is set to NONE formatting. Sometimes, editors will put in quote marks which confuses my html code. How do I convert any special chars like the qoute mark to html entities? A bit like PHP's htmlspecialchars or htmlentities.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always do this with a simple plugin which runs unformatted text through EE/CodeIgniter's `format_characters()` method (though rather than use the plugin tag in my template, I usually select it as the formatting method  for that field or Matrix column).

I've [thrown it up on GitHub](https://github.com/amphibian/format_characters.ee_addon) just now.

Comment: That's a nice approach, thanks for posting!